# Using ComboBox selection in SQL statements

Tags: c#

I would like to insert a number, for example 112, into a table cell. The column should be selected from a ComboBox. For example, if combobox1 text is "name", then data should be inserted into column "name" in table1.

The code below does not seem to work:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 ('" + combobox1.SelectedItem + "') values ('" + txtbox1.Text + "')";
```

With a hardcoded column name it works:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (name) values ('" + txtbox1.Text + "')";
```

How can i insert the ComboBox selection into the statement?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) alert.

Comment: You can actually work without column name, something like. .CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 values ('" + txtbox1.Text + "')"; or 
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 ('" + combobox1.Text+ "') values ('" + txtbox1.Text + "')";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameters to protect against [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Do not add ' for column name.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (" + combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ") values (@VALUE)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALUE", txtbox1.Text);
```

Comment: the ' mention is correct. your code still is vulnerable to sql injections though.

Comment: don't use this in production in an uncontrolled environment though, since the selected item is added to the statement without proper validation.